# Transforming several data points found in one column to multiple columns

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKB6y.jpg

My input are all in one column. The information included for each data point are things like from:, to:, subject:, message: etc. I would like to separate these different information of the data points to several columns. The first part I did was use the textjoin function to combine all the information of one data point. Then I used the mid function to separate them into several columns.

My problem arises in two things: (1) The Subject part and the Message part in the input can have several lines/several rows but I need them to be included in one cell in my output. (2) We have several data points so if there is an easier/faster way to do this it would also be helpful. What are the best approaches I can do to resolve these issues or may I be guided to the right direction in dealing with this. Is this problem easier to resolve in Excel/Google Sheets?

Edit: Here is a reproducible example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LoIjP5P0hshjrXuhTfpmhuafkvqZFvMBGJnJrTvejs/edit?usp=sharing

Edit2: My 2 codes used for producing the results I wanted but only for the first data point.

```
=Textjoin(" ", TRUE, A1:A22,)
=MID(B5,SEARCH("FROM: ",B5)+LEN("FROM: "),SEARCH(" TEL#:",B5)-SEARCH("FROM: ",B5)-LEN("FROM: "))
```

One thing I forgot to mention, each data point starts out with (#)LogIn

For example: 1st data point starts with "(1)LogIn" 2nd data point starts with "(2)Login". Although the # inside the parenthesis will not be from 1 to n because everyday the # starts back to "1" again because my output is combining data from several months

Edit3:
Both the subject and message content they have variable # of lines. It will always have at least 1 line but there is no maximum # of lines(it will depend how long the message is but I think in average it's around 5 lines)

Comment: Hello. If you do [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help will be faster.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, I am still new to this stuff sorry

Comment: Please post your code into the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: In the sample sheet SUBJECT may contain 1 or 2 lines; and MESSAGE may contain 1, 2 or 3 lines/cells. Is this true to your real-world situation? In other words will SUBJECT ever run more than 2 lines? Or will MESSAGE ever run more than 3 lines?

Comment: @ErikTyler yes, for both the subject and message content they have variable # of lines. It will always have at least 1 line but there is no maximum # of lines(it will depend how long the message is but I think in average it's around 5 lines).

Comment: I encourage you to make this especially clear in your post. Otherwise, people may spend a long time thinking they are helping you solve an issue... that doesn't actually work to solve the REAL issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a not very elegant solution for you.  I don't know if this is just to automate extracting some existing emails, as a one time initiative, or if this is meant to be used to continually process incoming emails.  But have a look at [GKOutput](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LoIjP5P0hshjrXuhTfpmhuafkvqZFvMBGJnJrTvejs/edit#gid=876782578&range=C5) in your sample sheet.

I used two helper columns, in A:B.  Column A extracts the first row number of each email, by searching for the "(#) LOGIN: " string.

Then column B does the text join of all of the rows unique to each email.  This has to be dragged down, unfortunately, but if you fill a column beside it with numbers (using SEQUENCE(999,1) for where 999 is however many rows you want), then you can double click on the bottom right of the cell to fill it to the bottom.

Here is the formula in B5:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(
    textjoin("~",1,
      indirect(if(A5:A<>"","Input!A"&A5&":A"& if(A6:A>0,(A6:A-1),"")
    )))),"")
```

This uses the row results in Output column A to set the range of each TEXTJOIN, to limit it to the rows (in Input) for one specific email.  A5 is the first row of the first email, A6 of the second, and so on.  `INDIRECT` is used to build the desired range dynamically, as a text string, but this means that `ARRAYFORMULA` is applying to `TEXTJOIN` to concatenate one email (from Input column A), and therefore can't also work again down Output column A to do the same for the next email.

Then cells C5:J5 have the extraction formulas, to parse the long text string of each email.  I'm assuming the sample data you provided is precise in terms of the expected format, eg. "SUBJECT: " and "MESSAGE: " will be present for each email.  If not, these may need to be tweaked.

Here is the first formula, to extract the LOGIN datetime:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B5:B,"^\(\d*\)LOGIN TIME: ([0-9-AMP\s:]*)")),"")
```

And this one is for the Subject:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(B5:B,".*~SUBJECT: (.*)~MESSAGE: "),"~"," ")),"")
```

**Formula breakdown:**
It looks at the email message string on each row of column B, starting with B5.  It searches for the string beginning with "~SUBJECT: ", and then collects all text up to, but not including "~MESSAGE: ".  It then uses `SUBSTITUTE` to replace any remaining "~"s (from any multiline Subjects) with a space.  And it requires `ARRAYFORMULA` to work down all of column B automatically.

Note that a lot of clean-up is probably possible.  The first helper column could be incorporated into the formulas that do the TEXTJOINS, in column B.  And I'm pretty sure that there is a way to do an array formula for column B, but I can't think of it.  And the text splitting could be combined into a single formula, but I've left it separaate, to make it clearer what each REGEX is doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the steps/formulas you used to implement your code! I am still new to google sheets and unfortunately, google sheets and google data studio is the main technologies used in the job I just recently got hired at(I just started last week). I mainly used SQL/Tableau in my previous roles so although I have knowledge how how a database and how data is stored/how to combine that to tableau to visualize, I will have to come to speed on how I can use google sheets/data studio because everything from data storage to visualization will be done in google sheets/data stud

Comment: This particular task is I get emailed a pdf file everyday and what I do is just copy and paste the info so I can copy it to our google sheet file and ill prob just manually add to this master sheet since it's only 1-3 files everyday. When I copy from the pdf file to google sheets, it turns out like the one in my sample sheet provided.

Comment: Although I understand the forumulas and the logic, I dont know all the functions and ins/outs and strategies when trying to work with my data in sheets. What resources/guides did you use to start out and learn to eventually become a master in spreadsheets?

Comment: I was looking in the googlesheets reddit wiki and found out about Ben Collins 8 courses for 700$ and I was wondering if that covers everything I would need to know start and can I eventually be adept on my own using that as my base of knowledge. 700$ is too much for me right now so I want to make sure it will all be I need cause I wont be able to afford anything else after that.

Answer (score 0):

I found it quite complex and unable to answer in a few sentences.

Here's my solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LoIjP5P0hshjrXuhTfpmhuafkvqZFvMBGJnJrTvejs/copy

First I marked end of file to make it easier finding end of last message. Just added ***EOF cell below list of messages

Then I extract Login times using regexmatch. I cut it taking only 18 characters from the right. Query is here used to remove empty rows.
[image]

For TO: FROM and other single line cells I use similar method (just remove TO:, etc. using substitute:
[image]

Then I figure out where first SUBJECT: starts. I need a row number:
The same is done with SUBJECT ending (it's where MESSAGE: starts).

[image]

To determine row number where MESSAGE: ends I check location of next LOGIN TIME stored in Column B or end of file:
This goes like this:
[image]

Then extracting multiline SUBJECT and MESSAGE contents is quite easy and I use OFFSET function for this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response and also the step by step illustration and explanation of each step you took. I am currently trying to understand the logic myself and I think I am grasping it and Ill try to implement this steps in my data alongside the other recommended way by another user. It looks like both of the implementations suggested to me are giving the correct results so I will see which is more efficient for my current set of data going forward but I will definitely be using both implementations in different ways in the future for different data.

Comment: Also if possible, can I have your suggestion with my similar response from above: I am still new to google sheets and unfortunately, google sheets and google data studio is the main technologies used in the job I just recently got hired at(I just started last week). I mainly used SQL/Tableau in my previous roles so although I have knowledge how how a database and how data is stored/how to combine that to tableau to visualize, I will have to come to speed on how I can use google sheets/data studio because everything from data storage to visualization will be done in google sheets/data studio

Comment: Although I understand the forumulas and the logic, I dont know all the functions and ins/outs and strategies when trying to work with my data in sheets. What resources/guides did you use to start out and learn to eventually become a master in spreadsheets?

Comment: I was looking in the googlesheets reddit wiki and found out about Ben Collins 8 courses for 700$ and I was wondering if that covers everything I would need to know start and can I eventually be adept on my own using that as my base of knowledge. 700$ is too much for me right now so I want to make sure it will all be I need cause I wont be able to afford anything else after that

Comment: Hi, I am glad you like my solutions. If you appreciate this, please mark my answer as useful (arrow up at the top left of the answer). I work with spreadsheets for a few years. I did not complete any courses. I just use google sheets help and sometimes I search for solutions here or anywhere in the net.